# How do you change KVM VNC port at runtime, from the command line?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, virsh

Currently I have a virtual machine running, and I can see that with:

```
# virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     vmname                         running
```

Now I want to VNC into the machine, so I check the port:

```
# virsh vncdisplay 1
127.0.0.1:2
```

Port seems to be `2`, but I want to change it to e.g. `5000`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use port `2` of vnc console on `vmname` virtual machine, but you use `5902` port. You need to add `5900` to each output of `vncdisplay` command if you don't set up VNC port directly in virtual machine settings.

To edit virtual machine configuration use `edit` command:

```
edit vmname
```

And edit line like this:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='5950' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0' passwd='password'>
```

You need to restart (stop and start again, not reboot) virtual machine to apply configuration changes.

Comment: Is there no way to do this while the VM is running?

Comment: no, there isn't

Comment: You need to powercycle the VM, not just restart it. Stop the VM and start it again, for qemu to spawn a new process from the changed configuration, and start listening on the correct port. A reboot of the VM  will keep the qemu process running without changes.

Comment: @dyasny, thanks for your clarification. I changed the answer

Comment: I didn't find what is powercycle.... could anyone complete the answer?

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud turn it off and on again.

Comment: Hey, I'm late to the party, but you can change port while a machine is running with virsh qemu-monitor-command --hmp <domain> change vnc 0.0.0.0:port